# How to avoid display HTTPS certificate warning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keychain, certificate

When I browse with Chrome on a web site that has an invalid certificate for some reason (eg my NAS Synology using HTTPS protocol) a warning message like the following Chrome appears to me:

[image: Certificate warn]

If I install that certificate in Keychain app and I select "always trust", it should not warn me with that message, in fact in Safari warns me too but when I install the certificate in Keychain, Safari stop showing the ad, but in Chrome continues showing message.

Can you see my config:

[image: config]

Thanks for help

Regards

Comment: At first glance everything looks set up correctly to me. You have the cert in your system keychain. You've set it to "Always Trust". The strange thing is that Chrome is telling you the certificate is marked as trusted ("marcado como fiable") but then saying "You attempted to reach 192.168.1.50, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as 192.168.1.50." Those addresses look identical to me. :/